# Не переведено "Human verification" при появлении капчи

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, recaptcha

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скрин где-то упёр ...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ одолжил!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11166

Предложил:

> А не робот ли вы часом?

Comment: Батенька, да вы трансформер! [©](https://batenka.ru/)

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущий перевод был такой (голосуйте, если хотите оставить его):

> Подтвердите, что вы не робот

Слетел из-за того, что раньше "Verification" писалось с большой буквы.